# AWS CloudFormation force create or create if exists

Tags: aws-cloudformation

When I try to deploy (`cloudformation create-change-set` and `cloudformation execute-change-set`) the CFN stack the creation fails if some of the resources from the CFN template exists.

Is it possible to force override or skip creation of the resource if it exists?

Thanks,

Comment: That is exactly what those 2 commands are supposed to solve. Maybe you missed something. Would help if you could post some more details

Comment: No, these two commands have nothing to do with existing resources. They build the "diff" of existing STACK, not existing resources out of stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's one of the biggest limitations of CloudFormation - it can't handle existing resources. You need to remove existing ones and re-create them with CloudFormation.

That's why, if you are going to use it, you need to use it from the very beginng. Unfortunately there is no such stuff like `import` in Terraform.

On latest re:invent CloudFormation team mentioned handling "drifts", but there is still nothing available regarding that in live product.

--edit--

At the end of 2019 AWS finally introduced [importing resources into CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/) stacks!